# Angular и модульный backend

Tags: php, mvc, angular2

Буквально пару дней изучаю [angular](https://angular.io), вроде все логично, но задался вопросом - а как собственно это использовать совместно с backend частью ? К примеру  у меня есть небольшая cms разбитая на модули, каждый модуль имеет структуру вида:

```
-Module
 --backend
  ---models
  ---views
  ---controllers
```

Соответственно все файлы представления данного модуля находятся непосредственно в самом модуле. 
Можно ли таким образом разбить приложение на angular чтобы разные его части отдавались динамически ? Т.к. не совсем понятно как это все должно взаимодействовать. За основу взял [ng2-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin), скомпилировал проект angular, в итоге получил следующее:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>ng2-admin</title>

    <link href="styles.f0ac594d45b4b9a2d565.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>

    <body>
      <app>
      </app>

      <div id="preloader">
        <div></div>
      </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.5853ac59c2cfccc10fba.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.7fa51874d013990e71f8.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.6d1980287a62dbd24a44.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.f38f9669a40bce1796d5.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.d45e588ade0cfee2a231.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
    </html>
```

И еще кучу файлов, в том числе js вида

> 0.35a6b5085dfd55c3549d.chunk.js

Т.е. такой себе "монолит", который изменять динамически очень проблемно, на мой взгляд. По названию файлов проблемно даже определить какой это компонент. И правильно ли я понимаю, что все ссылки на бэкенд прописываются хардкордно как и все формы под каждый модуль backend, а потом это тупо все компилируется в такой вот "монолит" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На базе Angular обычно розрабатывают SPA(Single-Page Application). SPA's же в свою очередь коммуницируют с бэкендом по http, тобишь RESTful API. То что нужно вам больше походит на MPA(Multi-page application), а таких приложений на Angular я еще не видел и не слышал, что бы люди подобным занимались)

> И правильно ли я понимаю, что все ссылки на бэкенд прописываются хардкордно как и все формы под каждый модуль backend, а потом это тупо все компилируется в такой вот "монолит" ?

Да, на выходе получается монолит, под каждый бекенд-модуль, скорее-всего прийдется описывать свои "вьюхи", но сдесь с помощью Angular вы можете разработать переиспользуемые компоненты/библиотеку компонентов и использовать эти решения.

P. S. Читал как-то статью, где какие-то "большие", interprise-ребята писали MPA на Vue.js ;)

Comment: Понял, спасибо за наводку :)